# Can't comment on a question with no answer

Tags: support, comments

Every time there is a question with no answer the "Add a comment" button doesn't work.
Here is a list of facts:
1.    I have a reputation of 21
1.    The question was 13 minutes old when I first saw it.
Please help!

Comment: The ["Comment Everywhere"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege requires 50 points, so this isn't surprising.

Comment: @JosephFarah: Doesn't a popup appear when you attempt to comment with not enough rep? Doesn't a search in the Help tell the answer straight away?

Comment: @Jongware my apologies--I made it a point to obsessively read all of the rules on the site, so I already knew about the comment rule, and I actually made about 70 rep before I ever tried to comment :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have a reputation score of 50 before you can comment on anyone else's posts.